# Parsing JSON through Gson method fromJson

Tags: android, parsing

I am parsing an API through

```
ArrayList<Spot> spots = Gson.fromJson(response , new TypeToken<Arraylist<Spot>>(){}.getType())
```

My response is perfectly fine, but when I see the response through Gson.toJson(spots). It shows me empty objects, means it have parsed the first field of each object in the API but internals fields of each object is not parsed.

I receive null values if I access the internal fields which is obvious . Can any one let me know where the problem lies, why its not parsing any internal field? .

Comment: Can you share "Spot" class and Json sample?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use List instead of ArrayList.
When you create your json use:

```
List<Spot> spots = new ArrayList<Spot>();
gson...
```

And when you parse the response use:

```
List<Spot> spots = Gson.fromJson(response , new TypeToken<List<Spot>>(){}.getType());
```

If that does not work, please show your json and the Spot class.

Comment: it didnt work . i have  private Integer id;name;description;s3_content_url;user_id;location_name;
 _at;updated_at;lat;lon; as my spot data members. and api has something like this  http://api.spotted.at/spots.json?name=boot+bhae

Comment: The integer values in the json have a lot of "null" in it. I think Gson cant parse this and skips the object. Maybe you have to parse the json by hand to prevent errors on the "null" values.